# vb.net localdb traceflag and getting server log information

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, localdb

we use sql server 2012 localdb on our clients vb.net, winforms, 4.0 framework application.

Time to time we get deadlocked on some transactions so we want to enable trace flag 1222 and log it on server error log and then read it using XP_READERRORLOG.

Current users do not have sysadmin roles enabled, causing DBCC TRACEON and XP_READERRORLOG to fail.

We want to be able to do this seamlessly by the user, preferring not to run app in administrative mode.

1. Is there a way to enable sysadmin. (ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [username] gets stuck on permissions)
2. Alternatively a way to enable the flag and get error.log file location to get a copy of it. Maybe without using sqlconnection, sqlcommand.

thank you for the help.

Comment: so set up a deadlock tracing session...

Comment: That requires permissions as well, current user permissions are set as dbcreator and public.

Comment: don't do it as a normal user: get your dba to set it up...requires no app changes

Comment: its on the client app, there are too many of them to setup, might have to connect individual repeating clients and manually do it. Curious if this could be done on batch file level, I'll research it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The deadlocks are on client install with localDB, not server side. The DB resides on client computers.